# How to apply ngx-pipe "unique" with condition?

Tags: angular

I have a list of object contains a property: groupID, but only some of elements held the value for this property. In the template, I want to use ngFor with unique pipe for the list. But after applied, it also did for the property's value is null.

Is there a way I could applied some kind of condition with the pipe?

Below is the simple example for my problem.

```
list = [
 {ID: "001", groupID: "246"},
 {ID: "002", groupID: "246"},
 {ID: "003", groupID: ""},
 {ID: "004", groupID: ""},
 {ID: "005", groupID: "135"},
 {ID: "006", groupID: "135"},
 {ID: "007", groupID: ""},
]
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let l of list | unique: 'groupID'">
 <app-A [inputObject]="l['groupID']" *ngIf="l['groupID']!=''"></app-A>
 <app-B [inputObject]="l" *ngIf="l['groupID']==''"></app-B>
</div>
```

Then A component received two objects, {ID: "001", groupID: "246"}, and {ID: "005", groupID: "135"}, which are correct. However, B component only received {ID: "003", groupID: ""}, because the unique pipe also caught the empty value.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into ngx-pipes [unique pipe](https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes/blob/master/src/pipes/array/unique.ts) source code, you'll notice that you cannot pass any other argument to it in order to achieve what you want.

First idea could be to discuss that with the author and eventually you could come up with a pull request.

Second idea is simply to create your own pipe, here's my take:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'unique'
})
export class UniquePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(arr: any[], propertyName: string): any {
    const res = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (!acc.valuesSet.has(curr[propertyName])) {
        acc.array.push(curr)
        acc.valuesSet.add(curr[propertyName]);
      }

      return acc;
    }, { valuesSet: new Set(), array: [] })

    return res.array;
  }
}
```

And a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3sfcw3